# Error compiling for Git installion on Linux

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install Git on a Raspberry Pi 3.

I am following this: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-git-on-raspberry-pi/#installing-git-from-the-source

When I run:

```
sudo make prefix=/usr/local all
```

then it throws this:

```
LINK t/helper/test-tool
reftable/libreftable.a(block.o): In function `block_reader_init':
/usr/src/git-2.35.1/reftable/block.c:213: undefined reference to `uncompress2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2949: recipe for target 't/helper/test-tool' failed
make: * [t/helper/test-tool] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or can point me to something that can help me?

Comment: Undefined reference is a linker message that indicates that there is no definition for function or there is no library containing the definition of that function. Fast googling gave me that `uncompress2 (dest, destLen, source, sourceLen)` is function of [zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/uncompr.c). Have you install all the dependencies that shown in the article?

Comment: Uncompress2 is only in *some* versions of zlib; there's been mailing list chatter on making the reftable code—which isn't really turned on yet—pick out the correct compilation option automatically but for now you *must* configure your build based on your zlib.

Comment: @torek I have installed zlib-devel for building git from source code in oracle linux (variant of rhel). I am passing -lz -std=c99 flags on this line https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b6846d9dcd391164b72bd70e8a0c0e09776afe3/Makefile#L1247. I am passing std=c99 since without that I am getting some other [error](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7bc341e21b566c6685b7d993ca80459f9994be38#diff-1c67f843ddfdfea5499e634c6f3e9ee34fabb6e020aaad9188ba38771edd833dR14). Can you tell what is the correct compilation option you mentioned above?

Comment: @ThakurKarthik: I don't recall the exact configuration knob, but the 2.36.0 release notes say `* The build procedure has been taught to notice older version of zlib and enable our replacement uncompress2() automatically. (merge 07564773c2 ab/auto-detect-zlib-compress2 later to maint).`

Comment: That commit, in turn, includes `-# Define NO_UNCOMPRESS2 if your zlib does not have uncompress2.` So presumably you can upgrade to 2.36.0 source or add `NO_UNCOMPRESS2` to the build flags.

Comment: Thanks torek passing NO_UNCOMPRESS2 to make command worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to install Git on your Raspberry it recommended that install with `apt install git` . it's the easiest way but if you need to compile it from sourc try this:

```
 undefined reference to `uncompress2'
```

this error means that the `uncompress2` package is not installed. try to install these package on your Raspberry and try again.

```
apt install zlib1g-dev
```

or

```
apt install zlib-devel
```